# Problem calculating displacement from acceleration function using cosine

Tags: integration

What I am trying to model is the displacement of a constantly turning object that accelerates in the direction that it is facing at that time. Focusing on just one axis...

Acceleration at time t:
$$a(t) = - s * \cos(rt)$$

Initial velocity: $$v(0) = 0$$
Initial displacement : $$z(0) = 0$$

s and r are positive for the scale of acceleration and the speed of rotation.

If I (try to) use integration I get:

$$v(t) = { - s\sin(rt) \over r} + C$$

However, I assume C is 0, a) because initial velocity is 0 and v(0) = 0 only if C=0

Integrating again, dropping C, I get:

$$z(t) = {s\cos(rt) \over r^{2}}$$

I believe I have done the integration correctly; but it does not come out as I would expect.

What do I expect? The code below (a google docs script) indicates what I am trying to achieve - and crudely/inefficiently produces the results I am looking for...

`function z(t) {
    var s = 2;
    var r = Math.PI/2;
    var z = 0;
    var v = 0;
    var dt = 0.01;
    for(var i = 0; i < t; i += dt) {
      var a = - s * Math.cos( r * i );
      v += a * dt;
      z += v * dt;
    }
    return z;
  }`

What the code does is store in v the sum a(t) from 0 to t in intervals of dt. Similarly in z, it sums v(t) from 0 to t in intervals of dt (v and z are running totals within the loop equal to v(i) and z(i) at that time round). The values of s and r are arbitrarily chosen in this case.

The code above is slow and imprecise; but approximates what I am expecting. As dt tends to 0, the function can be made more precise (and slower!).

What I am after, however, is a single equation for z(t). (The code is there just to help communicate this question). My attempt at integration above clearly misses something... but I am not sure what.

Note also I then need to repeat for the other axis, where...

$$a(t) = s\sin(rt)$$

...however, once I know where I went wrong, hopefully I can then do that myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful with the constants. The second integration should get you

$\displaystyle z(t) = \frac{s\cos{(rt)}}{r^2} + D$

When you use the initial condition $z(0) = 0$, you get:

$\displaystyle 0 = \frac{s}{r^2} + D$, so $\displaystyle D = -\frac{s}{r^2}$

Does that give you what you needed?

Comment: Doh! Yes, I think it does.That was probably where I also went wrong on the other axis, where $$a(t) = s\sin(rt)$$, except there I need to introduce the constant to make v(0) = 0 and include that in integration for x(t).

Comment: In case it helps anyone else, for the other axis: $$x(t) = {st \over r} - {s\sin(rt) \over r^{2}}$$ given that $$a(t) = s\sin(rt)$$ for that axis. Thanks.